# Programing C - Auto numbering for lines?

Tags: c, numbers, lines

how could I make my function to look that way?

```
  F.Name        L.Name            Grade
  ......        ......            .....
1)Martin        Peter               7
2)Rani          Sari                9
3)Kara          Sandler             4
4)Charlie       Adam                5
```

My function looks like this
:

```
Martin        Peter               7
Rani          Sari                9
Kara          Sandler             4
Charlie       Adam                5
```

And the C-Code look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        char f[500]; 
        char set;
        char line[100];
        FILE *filename;

        printf("Name of file?: ");
        scanf("%s", f); 
        filename = fopen(f, "r");

        if((filename == NULL)){
        printf("error!\n");
        return;
        }
        else (
        printf("\n")
        );

        while ( fgets (line , sizeof line, filename) != NULL )
        {
            fputs (line, stdout );
        } 
}
```

so how can I put a number for each row,

First Name, Last Name and Grade?

Comment: Add a counter variable, and increment it inside the `while` loop

Comment: I tried but could not, maybe made ​​a mistake!

Comment: Why do I get the feeling we're doing his homework for him?

Comment: Thats not a Home work ;) , I have to learn because I have a test soon and thnks anyway;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like:

```
i=1;
while ( fgets (line , sizeof line, filename) != NULL )
{
     printf("%3d)",i);
     fputs (line, stdout );
     i++;
}
```

Actually you should use `printf` function if you care about output format.

```
printf("%-15s  %-15s  %-15s\n","F.Name","L.Name", "Grade");
printf("%*s %*s %*s",5,".",5,".",5,".");
```

place this code before wile loop

Comment: Thank you very much , it works with line numbers ;) do you have any idea how I can add F.Name, L.Name and Grade?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a counter that increments for each line:

```
// int line_num = 0 has been declared at the top

while ( fgets (line , sizeof line, filename) != NULL )
{
    printf("%3d) %s\n", ++line_num, line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int i = 1;

    printf("      F.Name        L.Name            Grade\n");
    printf("      ......        ......            .....\n");
    while ( fgets (line , sizeof line, filename) != NULL )
    {
        printf("%d)");
        fputs (line, stdout );
        i++;
    }
```